# Is there standard normal cumulative distribution function in GAMS?

Tags: gams-math

I want to code the following formula in GAMS,

```
 R(i)= Phi[beta*Log10(M(i)/W*D)]
```

Where 'Phi' is a standard normal cumulative distribution function.

```
  Scalar beta=0.34, W=70, D=41;
  Parameter M(i)/1 375, 2 450, 3 876,4 212,5 125/;
```

I didn't find standard normal cumulative distribution function in GAMS, is it available? How can I code this formulation in GAMS?

Comment: This and your next question appear to be duplicates, except the other one is for Matlab. That one is on hold, so I suspect this one will be put on hold too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in GAMS with extrinsic libraries, `stolib`. For cumulative normal, you would use:

```
$funclibin stolib stodclib
function cdfnorm / stolib.cdfnormal /
```

Implementation follows the syntax:

```
parameter_x = cdfnorm(a,mu,sd);
```

...where `a` is the point up to which you want to evaluate the distribution; and `mu` and `sd` are its parameters.

See here for more details: https://www.gams.com/mccarl/newsletter/news35.pdf or search the McCarl guide that comes with your distribution of GAMS for `stolib` (if it's at least v23.6 (I think)).

Comment: You might also check the errorf function, which is built in to GAMS. Just search for it here: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_Parameters.html